# Duplicate a javascript prototype instance?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm given an instance "aNode" of a prototype called "Node". [Following this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript), I attempt to:

```
var newNode = clone(aNode);
```

The clone function goes like:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Despite obj.consturctor() properly refers to aNode's constructor, copy is "underfined". Can't find why :(

Is this method wrong, or am I missing something :) ?

Thanks,
J.

Edit: here is what the Node prototype looks like:

```
Node.prototype = new PhysicsNode();
Node.prototype.constructor=Node;

function Node() {

    PhysicsNode.call(this);

    this.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.createStaticBody();
}
```

Comment: This clone method is correct and is working well. Do you have more details about your aNode instance ?!

Comment: Have to see definition of aNode

Comment: The code is fine, however using ES5 `Object.create(aNode);` is a preffered way to do this. Try using this method and tell us if it works.

Comment: @Sebastien Thuilliez  I've added the Node prototype definition

Comment: @Diode I've added the Node prototype definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Here

```
var copy = obj.constructor();
```

is just a function call and constructor function `Node` does not return anything. You have to use `new` keyword to create new object.

```
var copy = new obj.constructor();
```

Comment: All right! Thanks Diode :-) What's the best practice, have your constructor return something, or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
var copy = obj.constructor();
```

This line takes the constructor of `obj`, calls it and assigns the result to `copy`.

As `obj` is a `Node`, according to the line `Node.prototype.constructor=Node;` it holds that `obj.constructor === Node`.

Look at the function `Node`:

```
function Node() {

    PhysicsNode.call(this);

    this.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.createStaticBody();
}
```

This function is a constructor, it has to be called with the `new` keyword. If it is not called with the `new` keyword, it is just a regular function. As there is **no** `return` statement, this function returns **nothing**.

Therefore,

```
var copy = obj.constructor();
```

assigns **nothing** to `obj`, so `obj` is `undefined`.

Finally,

```
return copy;
```

you return this undefined value from your `clone` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it a good practice to have your constructor (prototype wise) return the actual object? Inheritance might make this tricky :(

Comment: No. If you call `var x = new MyConstructor();`, the `new` keyword creates a new object and sets `this` to this new object. So whatever `MyConstructor()` does (e.g. `this.property = value`) relates to the new object. You don't return the object from the constructor - the `new` keyword takes care of this.